# Direct2D Desktop DPI mulitple monitors

Tags: .net, directx, directx-11, direct2d, sharpdx

I'm trying to recreate some Direct2D graphics when I drag my window to a different monitor. Right now I'm trying to resize the font. This code gets called when the container that hosts the DirectX graphics is resized.

```
        public override FontResource CreateFont(Font drawingFont)
        {
            if (drawingFont == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(drawingFont));
            try
            {
                _d2dFactory.ReloadSystemMetrics(); 
                float dpi = _d2dFactory.DesktopDpi.Height; //assume that DPI is same for height and width
                var newFont = new FontResouce11(this, _writeFactory, drawingFont.FontFamily.Name, drawingFont.SizeInPoints, drawingFont.Height, drawingFont.Bold, dpi);
                Fonts.Add(newFont);
                return newFont;
            }
            catch (SharpDXException ex)
            {
                ExceptionWrapper.Wrap(ex);
                throw;
            } // Rethrow if the wrapper doesnt throw.
        }
```

```
        internal FontResouce11(DeviceEngine11 d3dEngine, SharpDX.DirectWrite.Factory factory, string familyName, float fontSize, int fontHeight, bool isBold, float deviceDpi)
        {
            if (factory == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(factory));
            if (familyName == null)
                throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(familyName));
            _writeFactory = factory;
            _d3dEngine = d3dEngine;
            FontWeight weight;
            if (isBold)
            {
                weight = FontWeight.Bold;
            }
            else
            {
                weight = FontWeight.Normal;
            }

            float fontSizeDips = fontSize / 72.0F * deviceDpi;

            // Create a format using the font size and weight.
            _format = new TextFormat(_writeFactory, familyName, weight, SharpDX.DirectWrite.FontStyle.Normal, fontSizeDips);
            _height = fontHeight;
        }
```

As you can see, I'm grabbing the `DesktopDPI` from the D2D Factory, as described here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/directwrite/how-to-ensure-that-your-application-displays-properly-on-high-dpi-displays#step-2-declare-that-the-application-is-dpi-aware and passing it in to size the font correctly.

But the problem is, the DPI doesn't change on a per monitor basis, even after calling `ReloadSystemMetrics()`.

It keeps using the DPI of the monitor that the application started on.

I'd like to get the DPI of the current monitor.

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10, there's the more fine "[DPI awareness](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/hidpi/setting-the-default-dpi-awareness-for-a-process)" concept.

See this article: [DPI and Device-Independent Pixels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/learnwin32/dpi-and-device-independent-pixels#direct2d-and-dpi). It has this note:

> On Windows 10, version 1903, `ID2D1Factory::GetDesktopDpi` is deprecated
> and the recommendation is DisplayInformation::LogicalDpi for Windows
> Store Apps or `GetDpiForWindow` for desktop apps.

> Although it is not recommended, it
> is possible to set the default DPI awareness programmatically using
> SetProcessDpiAwarenessContext. Once a window (an HWND) has been
> created in your process, changing the DPI awareness mode is no longer
> supported. If you are setting the process-default DPI awareness mode
> programmatically, you must call the corresponding API before any HWNDs
> have been created.